# Is it bad design to set self.delegate = self

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I have a UIViewController subclass (say MyViewController).

MyViewController.h

```
@protocol TargetChangedDelegate
    -(void) targetChanged; 
@end

@interface MyViewController

@property (weak) id<TargetChangedDelegate> targetChangedDelegate;

-(void) doSomethingOnYourOwn;

@end
```

MyViewController.m

```
@implementation MyViewController <TargetChangedDelegate>

-(void) doSomethingOnYourOwn
{
  // DO some stuff here

  // IS THIS BAD ??
  self.targetChangedDelegate = self;
}

-(IBAction) targetSelectionChanged 
{
  [self.targetChangedDelegate targetChanged];
}

-(void) targetChanged
{
   // Do some stuff here
}

@end
```

Based on certain conditions a class that instantiates an instance of MyViewController may decide to set itself as the delegate or not.

Foo.m

```
@property(strong) MyViewController *myVC;

-(void) configureViews
{
  self.myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
  [self.view addSubview:self.myVC];

  if (someCondition) 
  {
    self.myVC.targetChangedDelegate = self;
  }
  else
  {
    [self.myVC doSomethingOnYourOwn]
    //MyViewController sets itself as the targetChangedDelegate
  } 

}
```

With reference to the code snippet above, I have the following question:
Is it a violation of MVC/delegation design pattern (or just a bad design) to say:

```
self.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Isn't it some kind of actor model representation?

Comment: Its not bad, its wrong. Why would you set the delegate to self when you can easily call the method without delegate, as the definition of delegate in the same class. It is correct when you area dealing with some other classes, but pointless in same class.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish by doing this, can just easily call function with `[myVC doSth]`

Comment: @iphonic I agree it isnt the norm but there are reasons. especially when using subclassing. is it good design? .. maybe not, maybe yes BUT it is pragmatic. -- whatever i vote to close this as it will only generate opinionated answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's absolutely no problem with setting the delegate to `self`. In fact it is a good way to provide default delegate functionality if a delegate is not set by somebody else.

Obviously, the `delegate` property has to be declared `weak` otherwise you get a reference cycle.

To expand a bit, having read the wrong answer and wrong comments above, if you allow an object to be its own delegate, your code is cleaner because you do not have to surround absolutely every single delegate call with

```
if ([self delegate] != nil)
{
    [[self delegate] someMethod];
}
else
{
    [self someMethod];
}
```

Comment: i follow ur thinking ... for me it is mainly the naming 'delegate' that is the issue.. i usually have 'in between' methods like handleSomething or didCompleteX to do this.

Comment: @iphonic It is not defying the purpose of a protocol to have a class conform to its own delegate protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Its not proper way to assign self.delegate = self. 
for your functionality, you can do this:

```
-(void) doSomethingOnYourOwn
{
  // DO some stuff here


  self.targetChangedDelegate = nil;
}
```

and when using delegate:

```
if(self.targetChangedDelegate != nil && [self.targetChangedDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(targetChanged)]
{
   [self.targetChangedDelegate targetChanged];
}
else
{
     [self targetChanged];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is bad design to set `self.delegate = self;` it should be another object. Delegation via protocols are an alternative design to subclassing and you can read more about delegation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

And here is more on protocols:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html